# Constructing irreducible Lie algebra representations

Tags: representation-theory, mathematics, lie-algebra

In physics, a (irreducible) representation $\rho:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow\mathrm{End}(V)$ of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is often "constructed" by finding the weights of the representation, i.e. the eigenvalues of simultaneous eigenvectors $|\mu\rangle\in V$ of
the elements of a cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$. "The rest" of the representation is then constructed using ladder operators (eigenvectors of the adjoint
representations of elements of $\mathfrak{h}$).

I would like to understand, why these weights fully characterise the representation $\rho$. From the data above, the vectors $|\mu\rangle$ form a basis of $V$ and the action of $\mathfrak{h}$ on $V$ is then clear in this basis. But how do I know how an arbitrary
vector $X\in\mathfrak{g}$ acts on the basis $|\mu\rangle$ and why do I need ladder operators to create new eigenvectors while the $|\mu\rangle$ already constitute a basis?

Comment: The mathematical name for this (or rather a closely related) construction is [Verma modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verma_module) and their irreducible quotient modules.

Comment: Are you *sure* this is not a [math.se] question?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thank you for the reference! I will look into that.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I only ever saw this construction in physics lectures, so I thought I'd ask it here first.